# multiple operations on two dataframes using R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes df1 and df2 of different lengths and two columns as key columns. I would like to perform multiple operations on these dataframes as follows:

1. Replacing only the blanks (NAs) cells in df1 with corresponding values from df2 based on the key columns
2. for each key columns pair, the cells from both the dataframes where values are contradicting should be reported in a new dataframe

### df1

```
id_col1   id_col2   name    age    sex
---------------------------------------
101         1M              21  
101         3M              21      M
102         1M      Mark    25
```

### df2

```
id_col1    id_col2    name     age     sex
-------------------------------------------
101          1M       Steve             M
101          2M                         M
101          3M       Steve    25   
102          1M       Ria      25       M
102          2M       Anie     22       F
```

After performing operation 1, i.e. replacing NA's in df1 with the corresponding values from df2, I should get the following:

### result_1

```
id_col1    id_col2    name     age     sex
-------------------------------------------
101         1M        Steve    21      M
101         3M        Steve    25      M
102         1M        Mark     25      M
```

After performing operation 2, i.e. conflicting cells in df1 and df2 for the same key columns, I should get the following:

### result_2

```
id_col1    id_col2    name     age     sex
-------------------------------------------
101          3M                21   
101          3M                25   
102          1M        Mark     
102          1M        Ria
```

Can anyone help in solving these?

Comment: Try `left_join(df1, select(df2, -age), by = c('id_col1', 'id_col2')) %>% mutate(name = coalesce(name.x, name.y), sex = coalesce(sex.x, sex.y))) %>% select(names(df1))`

Comment: result2 may be `anti_join`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **result_1** you can use `left_join` and `case_when` after reshaping to long form:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

left_join(pivot_longer(df1, -starts_with('id_col'),  
                            values_ptypes=list(value='character')),
          pivot_longer(df2, -starts_with('id_col'), values_to="value2", 
                            values_ptypes=list(value2='character'))) %>%
  mutate(value = case_when(value == '' ~ value2,
                            TRUE ~ value)) %>%
  select(-value2) %>%
  pivot_wider() %>%
  type.convert()

#   id_col1 id_col2 name    age sex  
#     <int> <fct>   <fct> <int> <fct>
# 1     101 1M      Steve    21 M    
# 2     101 3M      Steve    21 M    
# 3     102 1M      Mark     25 M
```

For **result_2** the code is similar except instead of mutating, we filter and add an extra reshape.

```
left_join(pivot_longer(df1, -starts_with('id_'), values_to="value1", 
                            values_ptypes=list(value1='character')),
          pivot_longer(df2, -starts_with('id_'), values_to="value2", 
                            values_ptypes=list(value2='character'))) %>%
  filter(value1 != '' & value2 != '' & value1 != value2) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols=value1:value2, names_prefix="value", names_to="df") %>%
  pivot_wider() %>%
  type.convert() %>% 
  select(intersect(names(df1), names(.))) # to retain original colname ordering

#   id_col1 id_col2 name    age
#     <int> <fct>   <fct> <int>
# 1     101 3M      NA       21
# 2     101 3M      NA       25
# 3     102 1M      Mark     NA
# 4     102 1M      Ria      NA
```

---

**Data**:

```
df1 <- structure(list(id_col1 = c(101L, 101L, 102L), id_col2 = c("1M", 
"3M", "1M"), name = c("", "", "Mark"), age = c(21L, 21L, 25L), 
    sex = c("", "M", "")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df2 <- structure(list(id_col1 = c(101L, 101L, 101L, 102L, 102L), id_col2 = c("1M", 
"2M", "3M", "1M", "2M"), name = c("Steve", "", "Steve", "Ria", 
"Anie"), age = c(NA, NA, 25L, 25L, 22L), sex = c("M", "M", "", 
"M", "F")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: what if my columns are more than 10 or 20 in number and i don't know the data types of each of the column? your solution will be a bit complicated to implement in such scenario.

Comment: Good point, although you didn't mention that in the question. ;) 
See my updated answer.